# Java 8 Concurrency Simplest Canonical Form for Basic Task

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, completable-future

I have two questions:
1. What is the simplest canonical form for running a `Callable` as a task in Java 8, capturing and processing the result?
2. In the example below, what is the best/simplest/clearest way to hold the main process open until all the tasks have completed?

Here's the example I have so far -- is this the best approach in Java 8 or is there something more basic?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class SimpleTask implements Supplier<String> {
  private SplittableRandom rand = new SplittableRandom();
  final int id;
  SimpleTask(int id) { this.id = id; }
  @Override
  public String get() {
    try {
      TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(rand.nextInt(50, 300));
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
      System.err.println("Interrupted");
    }
    return "Completed " + id + " on " +
      Thread.currentThread().getName();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new SimpleTask(i))
        .thenAccept(System.out::println);
    System.in.read(); // Or else program ends too soon
  }
}
```

Is there a simpler and clearer Java-8 way to do this? And how do I eliminate the `System.in.read()` in favor of a better approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The canonical way to wait for the completion of multiple `CompletableFuture` instance is to create a new one depending on all of them via [`CompletableFuture.allOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-). You can use this new future to wait for its completion or schedule new follow-up actions just like with any other `CompletableFuture`:

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(
    IntStream.range(0,10).mapToObj(SimpleTask::new)
             .map(s -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(s).thenAccept(System.out::println))
             .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new)
).join();
```

Of course, it always gets simpler if you forego assigning a unique id to each task. Since your first question was about `Callable`, I’ll demonstrate how you can easily submit multiple similar tasks as `Callable`s via an `ExecutorService`:

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
pool.invokeAll(Collections.nCopies(10, () -> {
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(
            ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(50, 300)));
    final String s = "Completed on "+Thread.currentThread().getName();
    System.out.println(s);
    return s;
}));
pool.shutdown();
```

The executor service returned by `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` is unshared and won’t stay alive, even if you forget to invoke `shutDown()`, but it can take up to one minute before all threads are terminated then.

Since your first question literally was: “*What is the simplest canonical form for running a Callable as a task in Java 8, capturing and processing the result?*”, the answer might be that the simplest form still is invoking it’s `call()` method directly, e.g.

```
Callable<String> c = () -> {
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(
            ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(50, 300)));
    return "Completed on "+Thread.currentThread().getName();
};
String result = c.call();
System.out.println(result);
```

There’s no simpler way…

Answer (score 4):

Consider collecting the futures into a list.  Then you can use `join()` on each future to await their completion in the current thread:

```
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = IntStream.range(0,10)
        .mapToObj(id -> supplyAsync(new SimpleTask(id)).thenAccept(System.out::println))
        .collect(toList());

futures.forEach(CompletableFuture::join);
```